# Программа типа Paint

Tags: c#

Скажите я искал на ютубе, но не нашел как сделать программу типа Paint... вот я сделал форму, вот только не знаю как сделать её функциональной?

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: [Graphics Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx): начните отсюда и потом пройдитесь по всем смежным ссылкам, может что надумаете

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ролик с YouTube

- [C# Tutorial 28: How to make a easy paint software](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HxCq77mrQyo)

А также в довесок искодники

- [Simple Paint](http://code.google.com/p/simplepaint/) (for a tutorial on GDI)
- [Tutorial 1: A Simple Painting Program](http://utablesdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Tutorial%20-%20A%20Simple%20Painting%20Program)

Comment: Да вот с этим я разобрался, но вот скажите а как сделать функцию изменения размера кисти? Что бы например пользователь в numericUpDown1, мог выбирать размер кисти...
И последние чего я недопонял - это изменение цвета кисти..

Answer (score 2):

простейший начальный сценарий:

- изучаете как рисовать на форме или картинке цветной квадратик
- изучаете как считывать координаты тача/мышки + момент нажатия/отпускания
- по этим координатам рисуете квадратики во время удеражания мышки/тача